zip every month files and delete them
I have log patterns every day for artemis
I want to zip them and delete the files and save one month files in one zip
the files like this
artemis.log.2024-11-22
artemis.log.2024-11-23
artemis.log.2024-11-24
artemis.log.2024-11-25
artemis.log.2024-11-26
artemis.log.2024-11-27
artemis.log.2024-11-28
artemis.log.2024-11-29
artemis.log.2024-12-01
artemis.log.2024-12-02

I want to write a bash script

Do you want to write a bash script or do you want us to write the script?

Check man -k logrotate

Hi Mohammad! Welcome here! You sadly forgot to ask a precise, answerable question, and this is a questions-and-answers site :)

As Marcus commented, you need to ask a specific question and tell us what you've already tried.

A few lines from the last log file need to be copied into the beginning of the next month, so you have to hup the syslogd though there is another way. You have to put them somewhere + find them easily to use them.  The program you write should be, usefully, aware of the remaining free diskspace.

#!/bin/bash

# Get current year
current_year=$(date +"%Y")

# Loop through each month
for month in {1..12}; do
    # Makes the month two digits
    month_padded=$(printf "%02d" $month)

    # Match for current year and month
    log_files=(artemis.log.${current_year}-${month_padded}-*)

    # Create the zip
    zip -n "artemis_logs_${current_year}_${month_padded}.zip" "${log_files[@]}" && rm "${log_files[@]}"
done

Save as: zip_logs.sh
Change mode executable: chmod +x zip_logs.sh
Usage: ./zip_logs.sh
Updated:  Ed has a fair point, and I don't want to cause someone's data loss.

The zip command won't affect the source files. It just reads the log_files array and creates the archive.  If the zip process fails ("e.g. ran out of disk space or clashed with existing file/directory name"), the operation will abort, but the source files are untouched.

If you have an existing file/directory with the same name as the target .zip file, artemis_logs_${current_year}_${month_padded}.zip, a directory will cause zip to fail, and a file won't overwrite a directory. Now, if the .zip already exists, it will overwrite the file without prompting. Using no clobber,zip -n, solves this issue.


In both cases, zip will not affect the original log files.
However, zip's results do not matter, the script will finish and run rm.
Eliminating it, and using:
zip -n "artemis_logs_${current_year}_${month_padded}.zip" "${log_files[@]}" && rm "${log_files[@]}" 

It will remove the logs only if successfully zipped. This should alleviate any potential disasters!

#!/bin/bash

# Get current year
current_year=$(date +"%Y")

dry_run() {
    echo "Running in dry-run mode. No files will be modified."

    # Loop through each month
    for month in {1..12}; do
        # Makes the month two digits
        month_padded=$(printf "%02d" $month)

        # Match for current year and month
        log_files=(artemis.log.${current_year}-${month_padded}-*)

        # Check for log files
        if ! ls "${log_files[@]}" 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then
            echo "No logs found for ${current_year}-${month_padded}."
            continue
        fi

        # Check for existing zip files
        zip_file="artemis_logs_${current_year}_${month_padded}.zip"
        if [[ -e "$zip_file" ]]; then
            echo "Target zip file $zip_file already exists. Skipping."
            continue
        fi

        # Simulate zip creation
        echo "Would zip into: $zip_file"
        echo "Files to include: ${log_files[*]}"

        # Simulate file deletion
        echo "Would delete files: ${log_files[*]}"
    done
}

zip_logs() {
    # Loop through each month
    for month in {1..12}; do
        # Makes the month two digits
        month_padded=$(printf "%02d" $month)

        # Match for current year and month
        log_files=(artemis.log.${current_year}-${month_padded}-*)

        # Check for log files
        if ! ls "${log_files[@]}" 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then
            echo "No logs found for ${current_year}-${month_padded}."
            continue
        fi

        # Check for existing zip files
        zip_file="artemis_logs_${current_year}_${month_padded}.zip"
        if [[ -e "$zip_file" ]]; then
            echo "Target zip file $zip_file already exists. Skipping."
            continue
        fi

        # Create zip and remove logs on success
        if zip "$zip_file" "${log_files[@]}"; then
            echo "Zip successful. Logs archived for ${current_year}-${month_padded}." && rm "${log_files[@]}"
        else
            echo "Zip failed. Logs not deleted."
        fi
    done
}

user_input="$1"

if [ -z "$user_input" ]; then
    zip_logs
elif [ "$user_input" == "--dry-run" ]; then
    dry_run
elif [ "$user_input" == "--help" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 [OPTION]..."
    echo "Archive log files (.zip) by month and current year."
    echo "Options:"
    echo "    --help       Show this help."
    echo "    --dry-run    Test results using a \"dry run\"."
else
    echo "Invalid option. See --help for usage."
    exit 1
fi

exit 0

Just for fun, here's a script with all the bells and whistles.

Btw.: Since bash version 3.1 you can use printf -v month_padded "%02d" "$month" to assign the output to a variable without starting a subshell.

Btw.: Since bash version 4.0 you can use {01..12} with a leading zero.
